# solve sudoku puzzle using A*(A-Star) search

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence, a-star, sudoku

i want to solve [sudoku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku) puzzle using A* Search.
how to define g(n) and h(n)?? what should h and g be??

i want to code that in python but any pseudo code would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A* is a graph search algorithm that finds a shortest path between a source to a destination (or set of destinations).

To use A* on your problem, you need to reduce it to [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).

In your case it could be by defining a state graph - where each node in the graph is a partially full sudoku table, and an edge indicates you can move from one state to the other.

Formally:

```
G = (V,E)
V = { s | for each valid state s of the sudoku board}
E = { (u,v) | can move from state u to state v by adding one number }
```

Now, you need to find a shortest path from the starting state (your given board), to a target state (a full valid board).

Comment: thanks , i think i got it
but in this way, more memory will be used than "backtracking using DFS" , am I right ?

Comment: @ImanMirzadeh Of course, A* is less space efficient than DFS, significantly.

Comment: @ImanMirzadeh Also note that you don't need to generate the entire graph, you just need to generate the portion of it you need at each step, using a `next(state) = { all possible next states }`  function, you will use it to generate the portion of the graph you need at each step.

Comment: @amit yet another precise answer. Mind asking do you participate in competitive programming ?

Comment: @sasha I practiced in my faculty internals (qualifications for ACM), but got 2nd place with my team about ~3 years ago. Don't have the time for it nowdays, too busy working on my thesis, and I know I will invest a lot of time practicing if I do.

Comment: @sasha *on my thesis and raising my 3 months old twins